# How can I use C++11's range-based for loop to output data in a table?

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, for-loop

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // array< int, 5 > n;
    int n [ 5 ] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

    cout << "Element" << setw(13) << "Value" << endl;

    for ( int j : n )
    {
        cout << setw(7) << j << setw(13) << n[ j ] << endl;
    }
}
```

It produced this output:

```
Element        Value
      2            6
      4           10
      6  -1078585116
      8  -1217581056
     10            0
```

While I expected this output:

```
Element        Value
      1            2
      2            4
      3            6
      4            8
      5           10
```

I've tried changing small things, but they didn't work. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: If you want the index, don't bother using ranged-for.

Comment: Lingxi: Do you mind explaining why?

Answer (score 4):

If you need the index when it is much better to use an ordinary loop instead of the range based for loop. For example

```
int main()
{
    // array< int, 5 > n;
    int n [ 5 ] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

    cout << "Element" << setw(13) << "Value" << endl;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( n ) / sizeof( *n ); i++ )
    {
        cout << setw(7) << i + 1 << setw(13) << n[ i ] << endl;
    }
}
```

If you want to use the range based for loop then you need to declare an auxiliary count before the loop. For example

```
int main()
{
    // array< int, 5 > n;
    int n [ 5 ] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

    cout << "Element" << setw(13) << "Value" << endl;

    size_t i = 0; 
    for ( int a : n )
    {
        cout << setw(7) << ++i << setw(13) << a << endl;
    }
}
```

As for your code then you are using elements of the array as indices in it

```
for ( int j : n )
{
    cout << setw(7) << j << setw(13) << n[ j ] << endl;
                      ^^^                ^^^^^
                     element of n       using element of n as an index
}
```

Comment: Bingo. The example you gave is exactly what I needed. Thanks! Btw, why is it better to use size_t instead of int? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You array does not have 6, 8, or 10 elements. So you are reading from elements that don't exist.